# Как реализовать таблицы в БД для данных, которые представляют деревья?

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, алгоритм

В общем, название толком придумать не смог, но что-то в этом роде. Рекурсия-дерево)

Требуется следующее:
Есть список оборудования - и список запчастей к нему. А так же список неисправностей.
Так вот - часть оборудования, это те же запчасти, которые в свою очередь раскладываются на запчасти.
Например - водоснабжение(насос, труба, обратный клапан). Насос(компрессор, двигатель). Двигатель(вал, сальник)
Неисправность связанна с запчастью. Соответственно, если у запчасти есть родители, то они тоже должны связываться с этой неисправностью. Т.е. если неисправен вал, то по цепочке будет отображаться, что неисправен двигатель, насос и водоснабжение.
Вопрос в том, как это хранить?  В голову приходит вариант с тремя таблицами **Область-Запчасть-Неисправность**, но вот как это реализовать грамотно?

*А задача в том, что планируется проходить по этому дереву, отображая слева родителя, справа потомков. Соответственно, если у потомка есть свои потомки - то, при выборе, его отображать на месте родителя и выводить его потомков*

В комментариях можно указать, список каких технологий(фреймворков) вы использовали бы для реализации приложения, это мне для справки, почитать.

Comment: 100 раз обсуждалось http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE

Comment: Только что ответил в схожем вопросе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519586/7295