# Вывести все parent id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, activerecord

***Нужно Вывести все parent id?***

Пример:

есть таблица

```
id, pid
1 0
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 3
6 4
7 5
8 1
9 5
```

У id=9 pid=5, у 5 - 3, у 3 - 1, у 1 - 0

***Для 9 ответ: 5, 3, 1, 0***

*Как в SQL запроссе получить
родителей и подродителей для конкретного id?*

**Благодарю за ответы**

Comment: Для неограниченного уровня вложенности эта задача обычно решается уже в коде приложения. Для ограниченного -- могут быть варианты.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Думаю, это задача на [рекурсивный SQL запрос](https://habrahabr.ru/post/27439/).

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, к сожалению, MySQL их не поддерживает.

Comment: @cheops Предполагаю, что это задачка с каких-нибудь курсов и нужно решение на чистом SQL. Поправьте меня, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: В гугле вбейте "mysql рекурсивный запрос", найдете статьи по этому поводу. Там решения на основе хранимых процедур обычно, потому как с БД вам сильно не повезло, в большинстве других СУБД есть встроенная поддержка таких запросов, а в MySQL нет

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Вы дали ссылку на статью по рекурсии с помощью CTE. А MySQL не поддерживает CTE, так что рекурсия чистым SQL, без храницых процедур на нем невозможна

Comment: @Mike Я вижу у вопроса тег `mysql`, но вижу в тексте фразу `Как в SQL запросе...` и вижу, что вопрос похож цитату из задачника. Поэтому предполагаю, что тег `mysql` присвоен вопросу по недоразумению. Могу ошибаться. Жду пояснений от автора вопроса.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, а еще в вопросе есть теги `php` и `activerecord`

Comment: @Andrew Развенчайте мои сомнения, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 3):

Лучшее решение для такой задачи — паттерн [Таблица замыканий (Closure Table)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/193166/). Никаких рекурсий, никаких хранимых процедур не нужно. Уровни вложенности не ограничены.

Соль в том, что для каждой записи в таблице замыканий создаются записи *предок+потомок* (как минимум одна: замыкание записи на саму себя). Желательно также указать расстояние от текущей записи до предка. При замыкании записи на саму себя указывается расстояние 0, между записью и родителем расстояние 1 и т.д.

Чтобы получить всех предков определенной записи, нужно сделать выборку по потомку, равному идентификатору этой записи. Чтобы получить всех потомков — выборку по предку.

Подробнее — по ссылке выше. Там также есть ссылка на [первоисточник (презентацию Билла Карвина)](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - добавить в таблицу все промежуточные связи.
Для этого надо добавить в таблицу дополнительный столбец level, в котором будет сохраняться уровень вложенности связи.

```
// Удаляются все дополнительные связи
$q = "DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `level`>0";
db_query($q);
// Предполагая, что уровней вложенности не больше 10, 
// генерируются промежуточные связи с указанием уровня вложенности
for ($level = 1; $level < 10; $level++)
{
    $q = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` (`id`, `pid`, `level`) "
        ."SELECT t1.`id`, t2.`pid`, ".$level." AS `level` "
        ."FROM `table` t1 LEFT JOIN `table` t2 ON t2.`id`=t1.`pid` "
        ."WHERE t2.`pid`>=0 AND t2.`level`=".($level - 1)." "
        ."ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `level`=VALUES(`level`)";
    // Если не вставлено ни одной строки, значит все связи добавлены
    if (!db_query($q))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Эту процедуру нужно будет повторять только при изменении дерева связей.

Теперь можно получить все связи одним запросом, причём в том порядке, в каком они расположены в дереве

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 9 ORDER BY `level` ASC
```

Результат:

```
id      pid     level
9       5       0
9       3       1
9       1       2
9       0       3
```